# Docker build doesn't work for VueJS app with Vite working in development

Tags: docker, vue.js, vite

I tried to dockerize a basic VueJS app. I'm using Vite and I kept the basic files automatically generated when I wrote `npm init vite@latest client` in the terminal.
When I run `npm run dev` I can see everything is OK on `http://localhost:5173`, and when I run `npm run build` the files generated in the `dist` folder are correct.

Although, when I dockerize this app, I have an error. Here is the Dockerfile:

```
# Build env
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-npm-stage

WORKDIR /cno-vue
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY index.html ./
COPY public ./public
COPY src ./src
COPY .env.production ./

RUN npm run build

# Run env
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build-npm-stage /cno-vue/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And here is what I write in the terminal:

```
docker build --tag cesar/cno-client .
```

Here is the error I get in the console:

```
Step 10/15 : RUN npm run build
 ---> Running in 19b4ced0dc36

> client@0.0.0 build
> vite build

vite v3.2.3 building for production...
transforming...
✓ 4 modules transformed.
[vite:build-import-analysis] Parse error @:9:10
file: /cno-vue/src/App.vue:14:0
12:   <div>
13:     <a href="https://vitejs.dev" target="_blank">
14:       <img src="/vite.svg" class="logo" alt="Vite logo" />
    ^
15:     </a>
16:     <a href="https://vuejs.org/" target="_blank">
error during build:
Error: Parse error @:9:10
    at parse$b (file:///cno-vue/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-51c4f80a.js:32639:355)
    at Object.transform (file:///cno-vue/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-51c4f80a.js:42077:27)
The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I don't see any parsing error... Could somebody explain what did go wrong?

If I delete the incriminated line, I have the same error on another random line...

Comment: Quite strange. Are you sure those double quotes are real ones? I know that MacOS uses invalid quotes, that look like double quotes. Long shot but I have no idea about Docker unfortunately.

Comment: I edited my question, giving the complete source code... I really don't understand what happens...

Comment: I can only see a README with some instructions there, not a project.

Comment: Now that should be good (I forgot to push, I should sleep more!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I forgot to copy Vite's conf. I simply had to add:

```
COPY vite.config.js ./
```

Comment: OK, stackoverflow tells me I have to wait until tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

What has helped me wether I am using a one or multi stage setup, try adding "--", "--host", "0.0.0.0" to CMD like below

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY frontend .
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 5173
CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev", "--", "--host", "0.0.0.0" ]
```